# Stack Exchange API in Chrome extension

Tags: support, api-v2, javascript, getting-started

How I can connect my extension to the API? I tried to use this example code for connecting:

```
SE.init({
    clientId: 1,
    key: '?',
    channelUrl: '?',
    complete: function (data) { alert('connected') }
 });
SE.authenticate({
    success: function(data) { alert('ok') },
    error: function(data) { alert('error') },
    networkUsers: true
});
```

Which value I should put in `channelUrl`? And how I can register app and get token key, if it will work locally?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: If anyone still has this issue, comment `@` reply to me here and I will write up an answer. (But current low view count suggests very little interest.)  And [anonymous feedback is not promising either](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackapps/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=4616).

Answer (score 3):

I've built an [extension](https://github.com/AlahmadiQ8/StackFave/blob/4d4486ca250b824f4a9848d62babc51d22e0a1b7/dist/background.js) that uses StackExchange API using OAuth2 flow. I did not use the JS SDK and did it manually instead.

Here is how I did it:

```js
function auth(sendResponse) {
  const scope = 'read_inbox,no_expiry,private_info';
  const clientId = '12364';
  const redirectUrl = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('oauth2');
  const url = `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=${clientId}&scope=${scope}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}`;
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    { url: url, interactive: true },
    redirect_url => {
      const token = redirect_url.match(/access_token=(.+)/)[1];
      sendResponse({ token });
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: This code works perfectly. But make sure to add the redirectUrl for your app as `chromiumapp.org` in the `OAuth Domain` in  your [stackApp configuration](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) - reference (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169304/6908282)

Comment: can you confirm if the `OAuth Domain` needs to be `stackexchange.com` instead. Because firefox has a different domain `allizom.org`, due to which i'm not able to use the plugin in firefox.